# Как правильно описать действия при клике?

Tags: javascript, массивы, input

И сразу к делу! Задача : есть исходный массив(очень простой), инпут , кнопка , и квадратик! Мне нужно, чтобы когда я применял метод arr.forEach()(вводя его в инпут) и нажимал после этого кнопку, квадратик становился зелёным, ЕСЛИ ЖЕ код, введённый мною не верный, то квадратик окрашивался в красный цвет!

Я уже перепробовал много способов, то, что вы видите ниже, можно вставить прямиком в codepen, ну или как хотите, скажем так , этот код это уже крик отчаяния!

Итак, моя логика. . . (последнее , что уже пришло в голову)

Финальный результат - это преобразование исходного массива ( [1,2,3] ) к ( [10,20,30] ), казалось бы , нужно просто применить к каждому элементу массива ...*10, очень простая задача, для этого прописываю в инпуте.  arr.forEach(function(element, index, array){array[index]=element*10}) , тем самым (на сколько я знаю) я изменяю значения исходного массива (array[index]=element*10) , выполняя операцию присваивания, ведь так? Далее, я создал переменную(больше от отчаяния и собственной беспомощности), чтобы уже наверняка сравнивать результат, назвал её var best=[10,20,30](конечный результат, преобразования массива через тот форыч, который я написал выше), так? В теле обработчика события клика по кнопке я прописал условие, что приведённые к общему ТЕКСТОВОМУ значению arr и best должны быть вроде -бы равны , то-есть блок if(arr.toString()===best.toString()) должен вернуть true, и соответственно квадратик должен стать зелёным (условие прописано в теле if()-блока) , но этого как вы уже поняли не происходит!
Я так-же пытался прописывать в if()-блоке инструкцию if(eval(si.value)==="10,20,30"), то-же не помогло! В общем я чот уже запутался. 
Убедительная просьба , если у вас есть время, объяснить почему мой код не работает , на нативном js а не на jquery (его я вообще пока ещё не бум бум) ! Спасибо за внимания, буду рад услышать ответы!

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
var si = document.getElementById("some-input");
var btn = document.getElementById("some-btn");
var kv = document.getElementById("kvadratik");
var best=[10,20,30]

btn.onclick=function(){
  if(arr.toString()===best.toString()){
    kv.style.background="green";
  }else{
    kv.style.background="red";
  }
};
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.some-input{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.some-btn{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.kvadratik{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Исходный массив : </h3><br>
    <p>arr = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]</p><br>
    <input type="text" class="some-input" id="some-input" placeholder="Поле..">
    <input type="button" class="some-btn" id="some-btn" value="Кнопка">
    <div class="kvadratik" id="kvadratik"></div>
</div>
```

};

---

Хм, продолжаю тему того, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы было понятнее! Этот пример прям тютя в тютю покажет то, что я хочу! Итак, когда мы вводим что-либо в инпут, то запускается функция эвал(по нажатию разумеется), и превращает то, что мы вводим в КОД!Например.
1) 1+1 в нашем квадратике появляется 2
2) arr.reverse()в нашем квадратике появляется перевёрнутый массив
3) arr.sort(function(value){return value>2}) в нашем квадратике появляется 3(т.к она одна удовлетворяет требованиям)
НО БЛИН, когда я ввожу arr.forEach(function(element, index, array){array[i]=element*10})
возвращается undefined. . . ПОЧЕМУ? Вот что мне собственно и нужно узнать . . . Почему функция эвал прекрасно понимает другие методы, которые я пишу, НО напрочь октазывается понимать forEach()? Поправьте пожалуйста , если я где-то допускаю ошибку!

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
var si = document.getElementById("some-input");
var btn = document.getElementById("some-btn");
var kv = document.getElementById("kvadratik");
var best=[10,20,30];


btn.onclick=function(){
  kv.innerHTML=eval(si.value)
};
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.some-input{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.some-btn{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.kvadratik{
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Исходный массив : </h3><br>
    <p>arr = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]</p><br>
    <input type="text" class="some-input" id="some-input" placeholder="Поле..">
    <input type="button" class="some-btn" id="some-btn" value="Кнопка">
    <p class="kvadratik" id="kvadratik"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: а каким образом в Вашем коде forEach применяется к исходному массиву? где это прописано?

Comment: и что Вы вообще хотите проверять после нажатия на кнопку? правильно ли заполнен инпут? так для этого ничего не надо сделать с массивом - просто значение проверяйте. или как это у Вас работает?

Comment: А где у вас код, который отвечает за преобразование текста из инпута в код?

Comment: а как вообще сделать чтобы код применялся к исходному массиву по клику? Я просто подобный пример уже реализовывал через eval(si.value) - получалось что функция eval преобразовывала то, что я написал в инпуте в код, и он выполнялся, а уже потом я сравнивал получившееся значение с [10,20,30] , хотя результата тоже не было.

Comment: Что я необходимо ввести в инпут, чтоб kvadratik становился зеленый после клика ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, собственно, назначение Вашего eval, согласно задания, изменить массив arr. Вот его и выводите после `eval`. A `arr.forEach` никакой результат не возвращает, совсем...

Для тестирования можно вводить вашу конструкцию (только ошибку в ней исправить i -> index)

```
arr.forEach(function(element, index, array){array[index]=element*10})
```

Или что попроще:

```
arr = [10,20,30]
```

И, кстати, следует восстанавливать значение `arr` после каждой попытки.

И помните, через `eval()` можно весь скрипт кувырком послать...

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var si = document.getElementById("some-input");
var btn = document.getElementById("some-btn");
var kv = document.getElementById("kvadratik");
var best = [10, 20, 30];


btn.onclick = function() {
  eval(si.value)
  kv.innerHTML = arr;
  if (arr.toString() === best.toString()) {
    kv.style.background = "green";
  } else {
    kv.style.background = "red";
  }
  arr = [1, 2, 3];
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.some-input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.some-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.kvadratik {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>Исходный массив : </h3><br>
  <p>arr = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]</p><br>
  <input type="text" class="some-input" id="some-input" placeholder="Поле..">
  <input type="button" class="some-btn" id="some-btn" value="Кнопка">
  <p class="kvadratik" id="kvadratik"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sergey Nudnov, спасибо ! Работает, правда несколько нюансов. Уже не первый раз вижу, что окружающие относятся с недоверием к этой eval() , с чем это связанно, она же просто вычисляет то, что написанно в текстовом режиме , или нет? И второй вопрос чуть по прощще, какая обязательно ли прописывать return array[index]=element*10 ? Почему раздницы судя по зелёному квадратику нету? с инструкцией return и без неё?

Comment: Пока `eval` используется для обработки кода текущего пользователя, и нет шансов, что ввод одного пользователя будет показан с использованием `eval` другому, то оно вполне допустимо. А насчет `return`, так он же нигде и не прописан. Или я не понял вопрос? Кстати, если мой ответ выше Вас удовлетворил, то пометьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый ответ, нажав на `v` под счетчиком голосов

Comment: Sergey Nudnov, упс, извини, не вкурсе был про этот "лайк" , поставил, всё работает, как вы и посоветловали.